# How To get list of cities of selected country if country is not an entity using Dynamic Generation for Submitted Forms

Tags: symfony

I have an entity Travel and would like to dispaly list of cities of the selected country in the add form.

I have applied the example in the documentation : [http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#dynamic-generation-for-submitted-forms][1]

In this example , sport is an entity and it has a method called **getAvailablePositions()** but in my example country is not an entity , it is **CountryType::class**.

If I have to do like in the example in the documentation so I **must instantiate un entity Country but I don't have one**

```
$formModifier = function (FormInterface $form, Country $country = null) {

       // Country doesn't exist , this is wrong
        $cities = null === $country ? array() : $country->getCities();

        $form->add('city', EntityType::class, array(
            'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\City',
            'choices' => $cities,
            'choice_label' => 'name',
            'label' => 'City',
            'multiple' => false,
            'expanded' => false,
            'required' => false,

        ));
    };
```

This is the Entity City

```
class City
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
 *
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="country", type="string", length=5)
 */
private $country;
```

This is the **CityType**

```
//CityType

$builder
        ->add('name', TextType::class, array(
            'label' => 'Name',
        ))
        ->add('country', CountryType::class, array(
            'label' => 'Country',
            'placeholder' => 'Country',
        ))
    ;
```

[1]:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#dynamic-generation-for-submitted-forms

Answer (score 1):

as seen [HERE](https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/reference/forms/types/country.html) the countrype::class uses as default

> Symfony\Component\Intl\Intl::getRegionBundle()->getCountryNames()

So if we watch the Intl component [HERE](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/intl.html) you will see that you can retrieve an specific country like this

> $country = Intl::getRegionBundle()->getCountryName('GB');

So, that said : 
As you **do not want** to create an entity "country" with your own logic you could  create a static method "getCitiesByCountry" in entity city that will call his repository to retrieve the cities of that country *(where country like '')*. The above i only mentioned because if "country" is a string remember that the CountryType::Class will return only two letters (THIS ARE THE ONES YOU SHOULD PERSIST IN EACH CITY AS THEY ARE GLOBAL, NOT THE FULL NAME), and use the above methods according to your logic to translate before render.
Let me know if you disagree

Comment: Thanks ! glad to help , mark it as correct answer if it's the case :P. It will help my user